# crystal crosstab need to limit columns # of columns

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I am using a Crystal crosstab.  My rows are lab results and my columns are dates.  I am sorting the dates in descending order so that the most current dates are listed first.  I know I can use the TopN formula for rows to limit to a certain number of rows but I need to limit it to a certain number of columns preferably 10.  In the example below I would not want to show anything after 10/10/11.

```
     10/1/12  9/3/12  7/16/12  5/8/12  4/22/12  3/17/12  1/9/12  12/3/11  11/15/11 10/10/11  9/23/11  8/18/11 7/7/11  6/8/11
```

Calcium      8.5    9       9.1       9      8.9       8.9     9        9        9        9        9        9      8.9     9
Vitamin D     45    45       51       49      56        50     51      55        60       66       60       59      60     61

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Jill

Answer (score 0):

I think the cross tab can only limit columns if the names are specified which will not be possible with dates.

There are two possible work arounds I can think of:

1 - limit via the query:

Go to Report > Select Expert > Record and select the date field, click formula then add this formula (for 10/10/2011):

```
{Mytable.DateField} < Date (2011, 10, 10)
```

or for a dynamic date (older than 1 year):

```
{Mytable.DateField} < DateAdd ("yyyy", -1, CurrentDate)
```

2 - The other option is to create cross-tab as a standard report, this means the dates will be vertical rather than horizontal.
You can add a group to the report by date then add values for each type as summaries, let me know if you prefer this and I can explain in more detail.